# Doubts re. Play 2.5 with silhouette 4.0 seed project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, mailer, reactivemongo, silhouette

I have created sample seed project with help of existing activator seed samples.

Project basically does User/Password authentication with role based authorization. You can find full source code at https://github.com/pariksheet/dribble.

#### Technologies:

1. Play 2.5.3
2. play-silhouette 4.0.0
3. play2-reactivemongo 0.11.14
4. play-mailer 5.0.5
5. Scala 2.11
6. Mongo 3.2

Though this code works perfectly, I am not able to use latest features of play/silhouette/mongo. I have few doubts on using those.

#### Question 1: silhouette

In Module.scala:

```
Environment[JWTEnv](
  identityService,
  authenticatorService,
  Seq(),
  eventBus
)
```

Here, how to pass Credential Provider Object in `Seq()`? As, I am not able to figure out the solution. I am injecting Credential Provider in my all controller classes.

#### Question 2: ReactiveMongo:

In my UserDao.scala I am using old mongo api to get collection object:

```
val users = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")
```

Code throws warning:

```
method db in trait ReactiveMongoApi is deprecated: Use [[database]]
```

How to use database method? I can see another thread 
[How to setup Play!2.5 with ReactiveMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444605/how-to-setup-play2-5-with-reactivemongo), but it does not have a solution.

#### Question 3: mailer

I am using below config to send email through play app:

```
smtp.mock=false
smtp {
        host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
        port="465"
        ssl=true
        user="pari.test@yahoo.com"
        password="XXXXXXXXXXX"
        from="pari.test@yahoo.com"
}
```

Code works all good. However, I am getting warning:

> smtp is deprecated, use play.mailer instead.

When I use play.mailer configs code fails.
[Play Mailer plugin with Play 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077459/play-mailer-plugin-with-play-2-5)

#### Question 4: form

How to add validation in play form?

```
@(tokenId: String, form: Form[ResetPassword])(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages, request: RequestHeader)
@main("Reset Password") {
  @helper.form(routes.Application.handleResetPassword(tokenId)) {

    @helper.inputText(form("password1"))

    @helper.inputText(form("password2"))

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  }

}
```

In above form, I would like to add validation that will check if `password1` and `password2` are same or not.

Comment: Q2. As indicated in the depreciation warning, you should you `reactiveMongoApi.database` instead of the deprecated `.db`. You could have a look a the ReactiveMongo MailingList to see the discussion about this change.

Comment: Meta: looks like Stackoverflow prefers that you split your post into multiple questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Thanks marcospereira. Let me split this question into four.

Comment: Added separate questions

Comment: Q1 -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949447/play-2-5-with-silhouette-4-0-credential-provider

Comment: Q2 - Answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444605/how-to-setup-play2-5-with-reactivemongo -

Comment: Q3 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204037/play-2-5-with-mailer-plugin

Comment: Q4 - Answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203521/play-form-verification