# Play 2.5 with mailer plugin

Tags: playframework

I am using below config to send email through play app:

```
smtp.mock=false
smtp {
        host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
        port="465"
        ssl=true
        user="pari.test@yahoo.com"
        password="XXXXXXXXXXX"
        from="pari.test@yahoo.com"
}
```

Code works all good. However, I am getting warning:

```
smtp is deprecated, use play.mailer instead.
```

When I use play.mailer configs code fails. 
**config**

```
play.mailer {
    host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
    port=465
    ssl=yes
    tls=no
    user="pari.test@yahoo.com"
    password="XXXXXX"
    debug=no
    timeout=60
    connectiontimeout=60
    mock=false
}
```

**Error :**

```
     [error] application - error sending email
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:100)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:130)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:110)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPDynamicMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:117)
    at utils.Mailer.sendEmail(Mailer.scala:30)
    at utils.Mailer$$anonfun$sendEmailAsync$1.apply$mcV$sp(Mailer.scala:22)
    at utils.Mailer$$anonfun$sendEmailAsync$1.apply(Mailer.scala:22)
    at utils.Mailer$$anonfun$sendEmailAsync$1.apply(Mailer.scala:22)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:100)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:211)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927
```

Source code is available at https://github.com/pariksheet/dribble.

Thanks Pari

Comment: You might want to check if there is another config source, your email addr. are yahoo but the exception says that it can't connect to GOOGLE, this would indicate that your settings are disabled but other settings are enabled.

Comment: My bad. I have pasted wrong error message. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

All you need: `modify 60 (s) -> 60000 (ms)`

```
play.mailer {
  host (mandatory)
  port (defaults to 25)
  ssl (defaults to no)
  tls (defaults to no)
  user (optional)
  password (optional)
  debug (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```